# Connect domain to nodejs server hosted on vps instead on ip + port

Tags: node.js, websocket, proxy, port, vps

i have 2 react apps and a nodejs server (express and websocket) running on port 8000.

the express server is for generating random links and the websocket for sending real-time messages between the apps.

my apps worked perfectly after hosting on my vps server but after connecting letsencrypt ssl to both react apps, they don't work anymore because i have to connect to a websocket with secure connection.

so i want to connect the nodejs server with a subdomain i have from namecheap.

i have tried pointing the subdomain i got for the server to the ip of the vps but i don't know what to do after that.

should i create a new file just like i did for the previous apps in the sites-available directory, listen to port 8000, set server name to the intended subdomain and run a proxypass to the same subdomain?

This is my first time hosting on a vps server, i'm very confused at the point but my server works well when i just type in ip:8000 on my brower